# How to show drop down to display record by selected values?

Tags: php, yii

I have two types of users, One is `ADMIN` and other is `School_Admin`. There are many schools added in my application. Each school has its own school admin, School admin can view everything like payments records, billing etc. I have a created a page called `payments` where im showing all the payments to school admin. Here is my code. Im using YII PHP FRAMEWORK.

```
public function actionPayments(){
        $model = School::model()->with(array('payments'))->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->getState('school_id'));
        $this->render('//display/school_payment',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

So in View, Every `school_admin` can go to their payments page and can see details of their payments. It is showing all payments for that school using foreach loop...

But what i want now is to show payment details to `admin` for each company.
Basically, I want to show a Drop Down which will contain list of all school, so whenever admin select any school, it should show payments details for that selected school. If admin select school 1, it will show all payments for school one, and if it select school 2, then show payments for school 2.

[image]

How can i achieve this ? This is what i have tried so far..

UPDATE:

```
public function actionAdminPayments(){
        $this->pageTitle = 'Payments Report';
        $model = School::model()->findAll();
        $this->render('//reports/company_admin_payment',array('model'=>$model));
    }
```

Here is my view which is showing a dropdown select with all the names of school..

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name=id class="form-control" id="gender1">
                            <?php
                            foreach($model as $mod){ ?>
                                <option><?php echo $mod->name ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: I think you are used with role(ie., whether admin/user). So if admin, get all payment details of selected school and display it by using Javascript  Ajax

Comment: Yes. if user is admin then it should show all payments according to each school. but how will i do? any code help? im so confused.

Comment: Okay do you differentiate the admin and user login in?

Comment: Yes i do.. I updated my question with code that i have done so far. PLease check

Answer (score 0):

I have made a code according to your concept. Change it yours.

```
     <select name=id class="form-control" id="gender1" onChange="getPaySchool(this.value);">
     <?php
     foreach($model as $mod){ ?>
        <option><?php echo $mod->name ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <span id="payment-list"></span>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function getPaySchool(val) {
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "example/aa",//here url to get the details function
 data:'schoolID='+val,
 success: function(data){
    $("#payment-list").html(data);
 }
 });
 }
 </script>
```

PHP Functions

```
public function aa(){ // here i have wite smaple code, so you change according to your needs
  $users = DB::select('select * from userschool where active = ?', [1]);
  $msg="";
  foreach ($users as $user) {
     $msg .= $user->schoolname;
  }
  echo $msg;
}
```